# What is the solve for "Strings nested within an f-string cannot use the same quote character as the f-string prior to Python 3.12 Pylance" in vscode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, f-string

I am a begginer python programmer and I got a problem while making a programme which is:

> "Make several dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a different
> pet. In each dictionary, include the kind of animal and the owner’s name.
> Store these dictionaries in a list called pets. Next, loop through your list and as
> you do, print everything you know about each pet."

```
pet1 = {
    "name": "Phal",
    "owner-name": "Mouin"
}
pet2 = {
    "name": "Phil",
    "owner-name": "Saoum"
}
pet3 = {
    "name": "Pham",
    "owner-name": "Mukti"
}
pets = [pet1, pet2, pet3]

for pet in pets:
    print(f"The name of the pet is {pet["name"]} and the owner is {pet["owner"]}")
```

I coded this much but the vscode is telling me that there's a problem with my code.
The error says:

> **Strings nested within an f-string cannot use the same quote character as the f-string prior to Python 3.12 Pylance**

I don't know how to fix it. Please Help me!

I tried searching in Google but I were not able to get a solution.

Comment: I figured it out, guys. I just had to use '...' inside the curly brackets.

Comment: As the error message says, you can't use the same quote character--so use the other quote character, `'`. That is, `print(f"The name of the pet is {pet['name']} and the owner is {pet['owner']}")`.

Answer (score 1):

There 2 issues:

1.f strings have double quotes you can use single quotes in dictionary `pet['name']`

2.It should be `pet['owner-name']`

```
pet1 = {
    "name": "Phal",
    "owner-name": "Mouin"
}
pet2 = {
    "name": "Phil",
    "owner-name": "Saoum"
}
pet3 = {
    "name": "Pham",
    "owner-name": "Mukti"
}
pets = [pet1, pet2, pet3]

for pet in pets:
    print(f"The name of the pet is {pet['name']} and the owner is {pet['owner-name']}")

The name of the pet is Phal and the owner is Mouin
The name of the pet is Phil and the owner is Saoum
The name of the pet is Pham and the owner is Mukti
```